# Uninstalling a program

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to rewrite an imaging script in PowerShell that I originally created for cmd. I'm used to things being simple in command line such as

```
C:\Path\Of\File\Application> program.exe /uninstall /s
```

or

```
C:\> MSIExec /i "L:\Path\Of\File\program.msi" /quiet
```

Looking around for commands to uninstall a program in PS on here and I've found things like

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name = 'Software Name'"
$app.Uninstall()
```

The above PS code definitely reminds me of a SQL query which I do have some knowledge of, but not enough to understand how this code works in order to remove a program. If someone could explain how to use this code and use a detailed example it would be very helpful!

Comment: That last is a WMI query. WQL looks a lot like SQL.

Comment: [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Not sure the whole documentation for WQL is the best read for OP as he will only be changing the name of the software to uninstall it : ) @OP : Hi, have you tried to run that code ? It's quite efficient to uninstall a majority of applications (those listed in the `WMI` class `Win32_Product` you are querying). You have to be very specific regarding the name to target only one product ; check the name displayed in add/remove programs. You can also use the `%` wildcard like `'%Acrobat Reader%'`. OR you can call the native commands you already know from PS ^^.

Comment: To be honest I don't know what Win32_Product is. Whatever it is, that's where it's pulling the name of the software from. But no, I've tried multiple times and I always get an error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" which then points to the empty parenthesis in the second line

Comment: [`Win32_Product`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class. As for your question: did you check that your query actually returned anything (i.e. `$app` is not empty)? What PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: Does `Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name = 'Microsoft'"` return anything ?

Comment: sodawillow, it takes about 20 seconds to execute and returns nothing afterwards. Ansgar, it doesn't return anything so it appears, and I'm running PowerShell version 4.0

Comment: Perhaps you don't have a software installed with exactly the name you put in the query. Try a wildcard match: `SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name LIKE '%Software Name%'`